# Trying to rotate bird up when touch began, and when touch ended rotate down (SceneKit)

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, scenekit

When I touch the screen the bird is rotating up at the right angle, but is staying there once touch is ended.

The walls in my game have stopped spawning aswell!?

Here is my code, if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong let me know :D.
Will be very appreciative. Thanks

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if gameStarted == false{

        gameStarted = true

        bird.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true



        let spawn = SKAction.run({
            () in

            self.createWalls()

        })
        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)
        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([delay, spawn])
        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)
        self.run(spawnDelayForever)


        let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + wallPair.frame.width)
        let movePipes = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance - 50, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval( 0.01 * distance))
        let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes,removePipes])

        bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 35))

        let rotateUp = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 0.2, duration: 0)
        bird.run(rotateUp)


    }
    else{

        if died == true{

        }
        else{
            bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
            bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 35))



        }
    }

    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if died == true{

            if restartButton.contains(location){
                restartScene()
            }
        }
    }



override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if gameStarted == false{
        gameStarted = true

        bird.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

        let rotateDown = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -0.2, duration: 0)
        bird.run(rotateDown)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of information here but from what I see. When you start touching you set gameStarted to true. So your if statement in touches ended will not fire because gameStarted is true.

Comment: I can add more of my coding if that would help you? Do you think I should the touchesEnded statement?

Comment: I added the rest of the touches code if that helps! @Jaybit

Comment: I had to add my rotate action under the if died == true statement. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!